# Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails - Ruby on Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

My "child" form contains the following select:

```
<%= child.select :parent_id, options_for_select(Parent.all.map{ |parent| parent.grandparent.name + " - " + parent.name }, {:include_blank => true}) %>
```

On the "update" action, I get the following error:

```
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`database_name`.`childs`, CONSTRAINT `fk_part2_5` FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id`) REFERENCES `parents` (`id`))
```

Models look like so:

```
class Child < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :parent
end

class Parent < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :childs, :dependent => :delete_all 
end

class GrandParent < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :parents, :dependent => :delete_all
end
```

Comment: The plural of `child` is `children` - not `childs`.

Comment: I'm well aware of that, I'm a native English speaker. I just changed the model names for the purpose of this post. As you can see, I figured out my own answer, so I'm good now.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. It was my select form that was wrong. The actual value of the individual select options was not the ID's, so it wasn't able to update the table. Figured it out as so:

```
<%= child.collection_select(:parent_id, Parent.all, :id, :parent_with_grandparent_name) %>

class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :childs, :dependent => :delete_all 
  belongs_to :grandparent
  def parent_with_grandparent_name
    grandparent.name + " - " + name
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In [options_for_select](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_for_select) call you use an array of option texts, which is incorrect. You need to use an array of pairs [option text, option value]:

```
<%= child.select :parent_id, options_for_select(Parent.all.map { |parent| ["#{parent.grandparent.name} - #{parent.name}", parent.id] }), { include_blank: true } %>
```